# What to do if a router doesn't seem to start up?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking

It seems like a rare occasion since this isn't asked yet which surprised me a bit.

Since this question is rather general, I will shrink the scope of this question for you a bit.

My father bought a TP-Link N750 (TL-WDR4300) a few years ago. Now the problem occurs that the router doesn't want to start up for some reason. Funny fact is that the cabled ethernet part still works, but the WiFi part doesn't work, it does not want to reset, and the control panel (192.168.0.1) is not accessible. So it seems this router can't start its wifi module and whatever controls the firmware on that thing.

My question is now:

- Is there anything I can do in the first place?
- Can I somehow still force a hard reset even if the reset buttons don't work?
- Is it worth the risk/effort?

Comment: have you tried the EasyAssistant utility to connect from a LAN PC? https://www.tp-link.com/il/download/TL-WDR4300.html#Utility

Comment: Jep, but it failed and the wireless led isn't flashing. I checked the switch at the backside and it was set to on.

Comment: If a reset (as described in the product documentation) doesn't sort it, it's likely the unit is defective. It happens all the time.

Comment: Try a 30/30/30 reset. If that works, update the firmware asap. What you are describing with "the wired part still works" may be an emergency Management mode to get firmware back on it via tftp.(corrupted boot image) It's normal for some of them to no longer be listening on the IP number you had it set to if it's in this mode.

Comment: 30/30/30 didn't work. But I will give it up and use it as a switch instead @Tim_Stewart

Comment: dont give up yet... thats a wdr-4300 right? look at the bottom label and let me know the version number.

Comment: ver 1.7 @Tim_Stewart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are actually  pretty decent home routers, and if you are lucky enough to have a **v1.7** you can get dd-wrt on it. The unit may just be defective, but if its just corrupted firmware these are **well worth reviving**.

Solution:

1- Download [12-22-2014-r25697 factory-to-ddwrt.bin](https://download1.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/downloads/betas/2014/12-22-2014-r25697/tplink_tl-wr740nv3/)

2- rename firmware to wdr4300v1_tp_recovery.bin

3- Download [tftpd32 version 4.50](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/tftpd32_download.html) (**if you have firewall software, grant all permissions to tftpd32 and especially port 69.**)

4- set your PC/Laptop IP address statically to 192.168.0.66, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0 (the router will be 192.168.0.86 and won't ping back if you try)

5- Connect your computer to the LAN port 1 on the router (WAN port won't work for this)

6- Open tftpd32, in TFTP Server select server interface 192.168.0.66

7- Hold down the WPS/Reset button on the router.

8- Power on the router.

9- After approximately 7 seconds release the reset button.

10- In tftpd32=>tftp server, in the current  directory, browse and select folder with renamed firmware (in step 2)

11- The router will now download the firmware from your server and upgrade. **(!~Be patient and do not interrupt this process~!)** seriously be patient here or you can totally brick the unit.

After the reboot it should be giving out dhcp leases again, dont forget to re-enable auto dhcp on your computer.

Good luck to you sir!

This info came from the [dd-wrt forums.](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=278435&sid=70fab4b05dd17b0087c8f5810de48d9b)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently got one of these wdr4300 v1.7 as a hand me down from a friend, and it was on openwrt, tried to flash the stock fw into it within the openwrt web interface. It didn't like that and bricked.

It didn't brick in 'bootloop' but it turns on and only lights on are power (fixed, not flashing) and lan on the port the cable is plugged.

Tried a lot of stuff and finally got the tftp recovery method working; it asks for the fw and the tftp server provides it.

After that the recovery light turns off, and it stays there, not rebooting. Left it for a few hours in case it's a late bloomer and it's still there with the power light on and the lan activity light flashing.

Any ideas? I haven't found any info on that kind of brick (fix power light)

Thanks! (sorry for reviving this old thread)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.